# Cardinal number for a subset of $\mathbb{N}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

Following simple statement came to my mind when I was thinking about infinite sets.

**Statement**: *There is no set $X\subset\mathbb{N}$ that has cardinality strictly between any finite set $S\subset\mathbb{N}$ and the set $\mathbb{N}$*.

I have three question that I want to ask:

1. If the statement is true, then does it imply that there is no set $X\subset\mathbb{N}$ so that $|\mathbb{N}|^{|S|}<|\mathbb{N}|^{|X|}<|\mathbb{N}|^{|\mathbb{N}|} \space$?
2. If the statement is not true, then does it imply that there is a set $X\subset\mathbb{N}$ so that $|\mathbb{N}|^{|S|}<|\mathbb{N}|^{|X|}<|\mathbb{N}|^{|\mathbb{N}|}\space$?
3. If the statement is not defined, then does it imply that there is a set $X\subset\mathbb{N}$ that has no definite cardinality?

Comment: Is $S$ a finite set?

Comment: Yes. That is what I mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the Statement is meant to say that there is no infinite subset of $\Bbb N$ which has strictly smaller cardinality than $\Bbb N$, then the statement is indeed true.

The three questions are really "all the options" and exactly one can have a positive answer. And indeed the first one is true. The reason is that if $X$ is infinite, then $|X|=|\Bbb N|$, and therefore $|\Bbb N|^{|X|}=|\Bbb N|^{|\Bbb N|}$. If $X$ is not infinite, then $|\Bbb N|^{|S|}=|\Bbb N|^{|X|}=|\Bbb N|$ (or $X=\varnothing$, and then $|\Bbb N|^{|X|}=1$).

Let me also add that cardinality is some sort of measurement of size of a set which is defined by an equivalence relation. This means that *every* set has a definite cardinality. It just might happen that we have a definite set, but we cannot determine its cardinal *in terms of other sets*. But every set has a definite cardinality.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Now when cardinality of set is a Natural number, then does it imply that there is only two possibility: $|\mathbb{N}|^{|S|} = \aleph_0$ or $|\mathbb{N}|^{|S|} = \aleph_1$,   when $S\subset\mathbb{N}$ ?

Comment: No. If $|S|$ is finite (read: its cardinal is a natural number), then $|\Bbb N|^{|S|}$ is either $1$ when $S=\varnothing$ or $\aleph_0$ otherwise.

Comment: Yes, indeed. Thanks.

Comment: By the way, what is your personal intuition: if a set is either finite or infinite (by axiom), then how much room there is for CH to be false? That "quantum jump" must have troubled Cantor. I do know that $ZF$ is a axiomatized system so I'm not going to cry about it.

Comment: You should click on my profile, go to my homepage, click "Blog" and read the newest post.